# DIY 4S Li-Ion battery pack

Tags: batteries, usb, charger, portable

I am in need of some help designing my battery pack. I have a few concerns, mostly around charging.

My plans consist of using a microUSB boost converter to bring the voltage to 16.8V for charging. This will go into a balancing charging BMS board hooked to four 18650 LG MJ1's. The output from those will go to a buck converter to bring the voltage to 12V and be hooked into a USB-PD car chargers guts. If the design is right I should get my USB-PD charging capability, an ability to charge the batteries with a CV setup.

The CV setup has me worried. I have seen posts warning about the high amps a highly discharged 18650 pack can pull when charging on CV alone. Since I plan on really only charging at 5V 1A (boosted to 16.8V) or at max 2A (again, boosted), do I need to worry about that? I am by no means an electronics expert and that is why I am asking.

I've seen some posts suggest wiring a resistor in series with the BMS to lower the number of amps that could be pulled. Through my poor calculations, I figured the required resistance to be around 56 ohms. Is this required? I don't want to starve the batteries of charging capability unless I have to.

If you have any questions or ideas for my build let me know!

[image]

I said screw it, I will find out temps and potential problems with the circuit to hopefully answer some questions others like myself may have. These will be coupled to a 4S setup with LG MJ1 cells. Here are my purchases:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, you said to boost "the voltage" to 16.8V for charging, which voltage are you referring to?

then you mentioned that you plan to charge at 5V1A, can you make your intention clear? A block diagram of your setup with the voltage level you need would help.

Comment: I added the picture and I am glad you suggested adding one. It raised another question I have. Do I have to worry about electrical flow to the boost converter? Would a diode remedy this? Is it necessary?

Comment: See if you can find a circuit that's specifically made for charging LiPos from USB, or at least a boost converter that guarantees that it won't pull more than a certain amount.  In general you charge a LiPo with a CC/CV charger -- constant current to the limits of the charger's (or input) capability, then CV once the battery's current demands have dropped.

Comment: The max charging current that the BMS can take in is 30A.
So if you have input of 5V1A = 5W, and after boosting it to a 16.8V, the maximum current you can get will be less than 0.29A. This is not even taking in the power loss during the boosting. 
I'm not sure if limiting it with a resistor can work, but if we treat the battery as a normal resistive load, then we are trying to add a Resistor of about 58ohm to limit the current to 0.29A when voltage is 16.8V, and the resistor will need to be able to dissipate 0.29^2x58=4.88W of power

Comment: the output of the 5V microUSB input will be used as input for your stepdown converter, so it's better if you can manually disconnect the circuit with a connector, adding diode will also block the power it is supposed to get from the P+ P- ports.

Comment: A diode after the boost converter and before the "T" off P+ and P- should still send power to the buck converter though, right? And I got about the same for the resistance requirement and power dissipation.

Comment: I have a problem finding a reliable Lion circuit. expecially one for 4S that can use an input of a microUSB. Could I put a 4S circuit after the boost converter to achieve the same effect?